# How do I monitor events using the Docker Rest API in C?

Tags: c, docker, docker-api

I want to [monitor events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/SystemEvents) from my docker daemon in a C application, but I'm unclear how to subscribe to that API. This is probably just a Rest API in C question. All of the examples I find with Docker do a single call and response.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there should be a better way to do this, but it's possible to just read off chunks of events from the stream:

`echo -e "GET /v1.20/events?since=1500032589&until=1500035000 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock`

You just need to track the time, and realize that `until` is non-inclusive.